# Display array of pictures and match with a 2 dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have created an array of pictures and a 2 dimensional array! Basically the images are items that I have for sell, somehow I want to display this images and right below them, I want to display information about the items like author, and price. Price should have a radio button..
I have tried to implement it, but first I can't get the pictures to be thumbnail size and secondly I can't get the information to go below the images.
Everytime I do it prints them separately..
Here is what I have so far

```
 $neat= readData('items.txt');
 $pics=array('isbn.jpg','isbn1.jpg', etc];
 #array actually displays;
 Array ( [The Boys in the Boat] => Array ( [author] => Daniel James Brown [isbn] => 067002581X [hardcover] => 19.99 [hc-quantity] => 5 [softcover] => 16.99 [sc-quantity] => 9 [e-book] => 16.99 ) ) The Boys in the Boat { author => Daniel James Brown isbn => 067002581X hardcover => 19.99 hc-quantity => 5 softcover => 16.99 sc-quantity => 9 e-book => 16.99 }
```

I have a function that iterates over the 2 d array and over the images...
but when I print it does not print them together please help...Also the picture are too large, I need them to be thumbnail...I am a newbie on php..I understand the concepts but implementing is not easy
here is the function that I have to iterate over the items in the array and display them...

```
foreach ($neat as $i => $values) {
print "$i {\n";
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    print "    $key => $value\n";
}
print "}\n";
}
```

please comment if you need clarification am working on this..

Comment: show us the actual array and function

Comment: dont put code in comments, its unreadable, update the question.

Comment: I just did..thank you